# Proof of the analytic Fredholm theorem in Borthwick

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, meromorphic-functions, fredholm-operators

I've stumbled across a proof of the analytic Fredholm theorem given in [Theorem 6.1](https://books.google.com/books?id=t7hq-yld_n8C&pg=PA80&lpg=PA80&dq=%22It+suffices+to+prove+the+result+in+a+neighborhood+of+any+point%22&source=bl&ots=uhWId93wy2&sig=ACfU3U2avXd227Ax9idDI5PFG45pb8jD7Q&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiC74bT7qjuAhVOQMAKHSjrDGkQ6AEwAHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22It%20suffices%20to%20prove%20the%20result%20in%20a%20neighborhood%20of%20any%20point%22&f=false.) in *Spectral Theory of Infinite-Area Hyperbolic Surfaces* by David Borthwick (see below).

Given the notion of being "finitely meromorphic" given in that book, how does the author infer that we can choose a small enough neighborhood $N$ of any point $s_0\in N$ so that $N$ contains only finitely many "poles" of $E(s)$?

He didn't define what a "pole" is, but I guess it's supposed to mean (in the context of the definition of finite meromorphicity) that a point $a\in U$ is a "pole", if the Laurent series expansion of $A(s)$ given satisfies $m>0$.

If that's the case, I don't get how he's inferring that $N$ contains only finitely many poles. In the ordinary definition of meromorphicity, it is assumed that the set of poles is discrete. Isn't an assumption of this kind missing here?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't get you. If a sequence of poles accumulates at a point p, this contradicts the validity of the Laurent expansion at the point p

Comment: @PieroD'Ancona I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment. My question is why $N$ as claimed exists.

Comment: At OP: What @PieroD'Ancona points out is that the set of poles is automatically discrete since it cannot accumulate inside $U$. Hence, such a neighbourhood $N$ as claimed exists.

Comment: @JochenGlueck Could you point me to a reference which shows that the set of poles is discrete / cannot accumulate inside $U$? I'm used to the definition of meromorphicity which explicitly assumes the discreteness.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: As pointed out by Piero D'Ancona, if the poles would accumulate at a point $a$, this would contradict the Laurent expansion at the point $a$ that was assumed in the definition. (I have included a few details in the proof of Proposition 3 in my answer below.) I'm under the impression that the main source of confusion is that Borthwick assumes the function to be everywhere defined, while more common definitions of meromorphic functions assume that the function is only defined on a smaller set than $U$. I've also explained this in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer with a few general remarks on what a *pole* is and what a *meromorphic function* is.

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be non-empty and open and let $X$ be a complex Banach space (for instance, the space of bounded linear operators in $\mathcal{H}$).

**Definition 0.** (Pole) Let $V \subseteq U$ be non-empty and open, and let $f: V \to X$ be holomorphic. We say that a point $p \in U \setminus V$ is a *pole* of $f$ if $p$ is isolated in $U \setminus V$ and if the principal part of the Laurent expansion of $f$ about $p$ is a finite sum.

Note that this definition assumes explicitly that $p$ is isolated in $U \setminus V$.

**Definition 1**. (Meromorphic function) A *meromorphic* function on $U$ is a holomorphic function $f: V \to X$, where $V$ is an open subset of $U$ and each point in $U \setminus V$ is a pole of $f$.

Note that, in this case, $U \setminus V$ is automatically discrete since every point in $U \setminus V$ is a pole and thus, by the definition of the notion *pole*, isolated in $U \setminus V$. So one does not need to assume the discreteness $U \setminus V$ explicitly here, since it's implicitely contained in the assumption that all points in $U \setminus V$ are poles.

However, in his book Borthwick apparently takes a somewhat different perspective on meromorphic functions. I'll rephrase his definition, using what I would consider a slightly more precise wording:

**Definition 2.** (Meromorphic functions, again) Let us call a function $f: U \to X$ *B-meromorphic* if the following condition is satisfied: for each point $a \in U$ there exists an open ball $D \subseteq U$ with center $a$, an integer $m \ge 0$ and vectors $A_{-m}, A_{-m+1}, \dots, A_0, A_1, A_2, \dots \in X$ such that
$$
  (*) \quad
  f(z) = \sum_{k=-m}^\infty A_k(z-a)^k
  \qquad 
  \text{for all } z \in D \setminus \{a\},
$$
where the series converges in norm.

Now, if $f: V \to X$ is meromorphic, we can clearly extend it to a B-meromorphic function by assigning arbitrary values to it on $U \setminus V$. But we also have the converse implication; more precisely:

**Proposition 3.** Let $f: U \to X$ be B-meromorphic and let $E \subseteq U$ denote the set of all points $a \in U$ at which the number $m$ from the Laurent expansion $(*)$ cannot be chosen as $0$. Then $f|_{U \setminus E}: U \setminus E \to X$ is meromorphic (in particular, $E$ is discrete in $U$).

*Proof.* It is a consequence of $(*)$ and of the definition of $E$ that, for each $z \in U \setminus E$, the function $f$ is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $z$ (including $z$ itself); in particular, an entire neighbourhood of $z$ is contained in $U \setminus E$. Thus, $U \setminus E$ is open and $f|_{U \setminus E}$ is holomorphic.

Let us show next that each point in $E$ is isolated in $E$; so assume to the contrary that $E$ accumulates at a point $a \in E$. We know that $(*)$ holds for all $z \in D \setminus \{a\}$, where $D \subseteq U$ is an appropriately chosen open disk with center $a$. In particular this implies that $f$ is holomorphic on $D \setminus \{a\}$.

However, since $E$ accumulates at $a$, there exists a point $a_1 \in E$ which is in $D \setminus \{a\}$. Since $f$ is, as noted in the previous paragraph, holomorphic at $a_1$, the principal part of the Laurent series expansion of $f$ about $a_1$ vanishes. However, this contradicts the fact that $a_1 \in E$.

So we showed that every point in $E$ is isolated in $E$. Hence, it follows from $(*)$ that every point of $E$ is a pole of $f|_{U \setminus E}$. Thus, $f|_{U \setminus E}$ is meromorphic. $\square$

Note that the observations above show that Definition 3 (i.e., the definition from Borthwick's book) has a somewhat strange consequence: the function $f$ is assumed to be defined everywhere on $U$, although it is holomorphic only on $U \setminus E$; in particular, the values of $f$ on $E$ are completely unrelated to the other values of $f$.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much for your answer. It helped me a lot. But please note that I'm used to a different definition of a pole: If $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb C$ is open and $f:\Omega\to\mathbb C$, then $z_0$ is called *pole* of $f$ if $z_0$ is an *isolated singularity* of $f$ (i.e. $f$ is holomorphic on a punctured neighborhood $M\subseteq\Omega$ ot $z_0$) and $$f(z)=g(z)+\sum_{k=1}^{k_0}\frac{a_k}{(z-z_0)^k}\;\;\;\text{for all }z\in N\setminus\{z_0\}\tag1$$ for some holomorphic $g:N\to X$, $k_0\in\mathbb N$, $a_1,\ldots,a_{k_0}\in X$ and an open neighborhood $N\subseteq\Omega$ of $z_0$.

Comment: Could you elaborate in your answer on why $U\setminus V$ is discrete, if we replace the definition of pole by the one I just presented? (I guess this holds even when "pole" is replaced by "isolated singularity", but I'm unsure how to prove it. And since there is a different notion of "discrete" out there and to avoid misunderstandings: I say that a subset $D$ of a topological space $(E,\tau)$ is *discrete* if for all $x\in E$, there is a $\tau$-neighborhood $N$ of $x$ such that $D\cap N\subseteq\{x\}$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: I'm not sure I follow your question: your definition of a pole is clearly the same as mine (except for the inessential difference that you, similarly as Borthwick, assume that $f$ is also defined at the pole itself - which is, as I have explained in my post, irrelevant, since the value that $f$ takes at the pole itself is arbitrary and completely unrelated to the behavior of $f$ in any puctured neighbourhood of the pole).

Comment: @0xbadf00d: As for the notion discreteness: your definition of discreteness of $D$ is equivalent to $D$ being closed and all points of $D$ being isolated in $D$ - which is, as you can see, precisely the property of the set $E$ in Proposition 3.

Comment: Please note that I did not intent to assume that $f$ is defined on the pole itself. I was intending to assume $N\setminus\{z_0\}\subseteq\Omega$ instead of $N\subseteq\Omega$.

Comment: BTW, how does your definition of a pole depend on the set $U$? Couldn't we simply substitute $U=\mathbb C$?

Comment: I guess my problem is that my definition of "isolated singularity" has an issue. [On Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_singularity), it is defined that "$z_0$ is an isolated singularity of a function $f$ if there exists an open disk $D$ centered at $z_0$ such that f is holomorphic on $D\setminus\{z_0\}$". Please correct me, if I'm wrong, but this definition seems to  be bad.

Comment: For example, if $f$ is holomorphic on an open disk $B$, then every point in $z_0\in B$ would be an isolated singularity according to this definition, since $f$ is clearly holomorphic on $D\setminus\{z_0\}$ for some disk $D\subseteq B$. So, how do we need to fix this definition? Do we need to define an isolated singularity to be a point not contained in the set on which $f$ is defined? Or is it sufficient to require that either it is not contained in the set on which $f$ is defined, or, if it is, $f$ is not complex differentiable at that point (or in a neighborhood of that point)?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Yes, the definition on Wikipedia is somewhat sloppy, as is also pointed out on the [talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Isolated_singularity) there. Admittedly, I'm under the impression that the questions you are raising in this comment thread are quite far away from research level mathematics, and are mainly about basic concepts from complex analysis. I'd argue that MathOverflow does not seem to be the right place for this. May I thus make the suggestion to rather consult a book on complex analysis about this?

Comment: If I'm not missing something, your $E$ is equal to $\bigcap\{V\subseteq U:V\text{ is closed and }\left.f\right|_{U\setminus V}\text{ is holomorphic}\}$, which in turn should be equal to the set of poles of $f$ on $U$. Right?